# Find peak disk usage on temporary filesystem

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage

I am using a temporary, in memory filesystem for some document conversion software (abbyyy, groupdocs).

I'm trying to discover the *peak* disk usage of this filesystem during processing so that I can tune the allocation of RAM accordingly.

Simply running `watch` on `df` isn't good enough, the file is too transient to see what's going on.

I started toying with the idea of `inotify`, but it lead to a bit of a dead end. Lost now!

I'm using a stock Ubuntu system, and mounting the filesystem like this:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /tmp/conversion
```

Comment: I also thought I'd be clever and use chattr to set append only (no delete) recursively on the directory, but because it create a temp dir and a file within it does not inherit these extended attributes.

Comment: I actually ended up solving this in a different way, however I think it'd be useful to know how to do this. A colleague suggested using strace on the process.